# Why can't I change log location for RabbitMQ's tracing plugin?

Tags: json, logging, rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04, trace

I'm on Ubuntu and attempting to use `RabbitMQ` with the `rabbitmq_management` and `rabbitmq_tracing` plugins in order to log my queues. This is actually working fine.

My issue lies with the fact that I want my logs to be somewhere other than the default location assigned in the `rabbitmq_tracing` plugin (in particular, I want it in my github repo).

No matter what I do, I simply cannot get it to change that assigned directory. I've even deleted the tracing plugin and enabled it only after having already change the `.ez` config file (turning on/off `rabbitmq` and my PC a few times in the process), but it was to no avail.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/09/rabbitmq-tracing-a-ui-for-the-firehose/

Of interest:

> There are two configuration options:
>
> "directory". This controls where the log files go. It defaults to "/var/tmp/rabbitmq-tracing".
>       "username". The name of a user as which to create the tracing queues and bindings.
>
> A complete configuration might look like:
>
> [{rabbitmq_tracing, [{directory, "/my/log/file/location"},
>                        {username,  "guest"}]}].

Mine looks more or less the same.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: "more or less the same". How does it exactly look like?

Comment: The location and name are different, since those are default values. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. run following command to locate `plugins_dir` and `plugins_expand_dir` 
   `rabbitmqctl environment | grep plugin`
2. go to the `plugins_dir` folder
   `cd [*plugins_dir*]`
3. unzip the package
   `rabbitmq_tracing-[*YOUR VERSION*].ez`
4. Edit the config-file `rabbitmq_tracing-[*YOUR VERSION*]/ebin/rabbitmq_tracing.app` 
   **IMPORTANT** `chown -R rabbitmq.rabbitmq [*YOUR-Log-Directory*]`
5. zip the package again under the `rabbitmq_tracing-[*YOUR VERSION*].ez`
6. run `rabbitmq-plugins enable  rabbitmq_tracing`